# how to sort dictionary keys based on the values inside a list

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    'key1': [v1,v2,v3],
    'key2': [v1,v2,v3],
    'key3': [v1,v2,v3]
}
```

How can I sort the keys inside the `my_dict` based on the `v3` item in the list.?`v3` is a floating point value.

My solution:
I created a nested list of list,

```
new_list = [[Key1,v3],[key2,v3],[key3,v3]]
```

and then sorted that list based on the v3 element.
Later I used a for loop:

```
for each in new_list:
     for i in my_dict:
        if each[0] == i:
           new_orderedDict[i] = my_dict[i]
```

This way I got the sorted keys using ordered dictionary.

Any optimal way?

Comment: And what have you tried already? Welcome to Stack Overflow, but do realize that this is not a code writing service. Rather, first you try and then we help.

Comment: There is also the issue that basic dictionaries do not have a sorted order, so sorting them inside `my_dict` isn't particularly meaningful.

Comment: It might not be meaningful for you @Jenner, but I have something to do with it

Comment: @sunilpawar What Jenner Felton is saying is that *you can't sort dicts, because they are unordered*. If you are using an OrderedDict, then say so. Regardless, since you have shown no effort at trying to do whatever you want to do yourself, and haven't deigned to explain what *`I have something to do with it`* means, you are not going to get an answer. Please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by sorting a dict, as well as showing what you've tried so far, the expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 1):

First, I must point out, since you're new to StackOverflow, that you need to make an attempt to solve the problem and show what you've tried. Secondly, `dict`s in Python don't really have an "order"--a `dict` is basically just a hash table.

However, a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (combined with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)) can do what you want:

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the end.

Here's an example:

```
In [130]: from collections import OrderedDict
Out[130]:
In [131]: OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): v[2]))
Out[131]:
OrderedDict([('key3', [0.12, 0.33, 0.971]),
             ('key1', [6.5, 0.7, 2.101]),
             ('key2', [0.1, 1.112, 3.14159])])
```